# how to export the content to pdf file and then verify the pdf file has been tamped or changed in its content

Tags: pdf, cryptography, verification, watermark

I am working on a demand that the website can export the content to a pdf file, and the site should have an api to verify the uploaded file - whether the file content has been changed or not.

My initial idea is to add an invisible or visible watermark to the pdf file at the time of exporting process, and in the verification process, the server could extract the watermark and verify the watermark.

The second idea is to calculate the 'file stamp' by using cryptography method on the file content, storing the file stamp on the database, then in the verification process compare the value from database with uploaded file value.

My problem in the first solution is I don't know the method or library to embed/extract a visible or invisible watermark from pdf file in node. The problem in the second solution is which cryptography method is best for calculating the file stamp

Comment: For the described scenario, a *cryptographic* hash (e.g. SHA256) is actually sufficient. The hash is created for the original and the uploaded data (the former is, of course, determined only once and then stored). If both hashes are identical, the data has not been modified. In addition to the hash, there is also the HMAC and the digital signature, which additionally prove authenticity besides integrity, but this is not required for the scenario described, see also [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5647).

Comment: the scenario is like this, this pdf file is a student verified certificate, the other people need to verify wether  this certificate exists and extensively the certificate 's content is not tamped by student, for example fabricating the scores higher. That is why there is a API to make 3rd party upload the certificate file and verify its authentication.